# coefficients in cumulative link models

Tags: regression, interpretation, regression-coefficients

I used ordinal package to build a cumulative link model:

```
require(ordinal,quietly=TRUE)
fm1 <- clm(base ~ . , data = df_reg)
summary(fm1)
```

df_reg is a dataset of 64 observations and 59 variables. The problem is p-values for the slope coefficients are NA. What should I do and how can I interpret the results?

```
data:    df_reg

 link  threshold nobs logLik AIC    niter max.grad cond.H 
 logit flexible  64   -0.00  134.00 23(0) 2.72e-09 6.0e+12

 Coefficients: (11 not defined because of singularities)
                        Estimate   Std. Error   z value   Pr(>|z|)
levelsupervisor         -30.58436         NA      NA       NA
levelproject/tech       -16.73024         NA      NA       NA
levelsenior             147.21086         NA      NA       NA
degreebachelor         -191.98532         NA      NA       NA
degreemaster           -167.23593         NA      NA       NA
degreephd              -357.77579         NA      NA       NA
gendermale               55.25386         NA      NA       NA
personnel2-25          -110.51872         NA      NA       NA
```

also (cumulative) odds ratios are either too small or too large such as:

```
   round(exp(fm1$beta), 1)
```

results:

```
   levelsupervisor      levelproject/tech            levelsenior         degreebachelor 
      5.216539e-14           5.421875e-08           8.567687e+63           4.186337e-84 

     javascriptyes              mahoutyes               scalayes                perlyes 
      5.139073e-16           6.048439e-27           1.086521e+37           4.032996e-93
```

I am wondering what the problem is.

Comment: How many categories do you have? If you have at least 5 categories, then you since you have too many covariates relative to the observations, you do not have enough degrees of freedom to get standard errors. Hence the "NA"s in the output.

Comment: I have eight levels in my response variable. Will lowering the number solve my problem?

Comment: sure, take a try.